# "Cannot instantiate abstract class" error

Tags: c++, oop

I have a simple abstract class (say A) and class which inherits from it (say C).

```
class C : A
```

The problem is the second one (C) contains code i need in another class; and i think it is good to split this part of code to separate class (B), and derive from it in classes i need.

**B(shared part of code) >> C(target) << A(abstract base for C)**

It is all okay - except one of abstract functions declared in base class (A)
is defined in B, **not C**. This cause my error, i think.
And i am looking for solution...

```
class A // a base class i need to derive from
{
    // ...
public: virtual bool Get() const;
    // ...
};

class B // only contains definition for get()
{
public:
    bool Get() const { return false; }
};

class C : public B, public A // firstly derive from B, than from A.. ??
{
    // so Get(), required by A is defined in B, which C derives from ...
    // and i cant derive from A because of that... I can't do that anyway?
};
```

I Hope i described correct..

Comment: But the class `A` is not abstract?

Comment: A is abstract and C is what i need to derive from A. But some definition of A abstract memeber is in B, not C.

Comment: This is not duplicate question. Lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A is abstract class, or if you want call Get() from interface A, you need overload virtual function:

```
class C : public B, public A
{
public:
    virtual bool Get() const {
        return B::Get();
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh yeah! This is more better! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can select which `Get` method to use with the `using` statement:

```
class C : public B, public A
{
public:
    using B::Get;
};
```

This tells the compiler to use the `Get` function from the `B` class.

Doesn't help if `A` contains pure virtual method though.

Comment: -1. Even if A contains don't pure virtual method, trying to call B from instance of class C throught interface of A will call A::Get, not B::Get, because keyword "using" is just syntax sugar, it don't override virtual function table for interface A. For example: C c; A &rA = &c; rA.Get(); // will call A::Get(), not B::Get(). That's not behavoir what need in question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to work properly `B` should inherit from `A` and `C` should inherit from `B`.

Multiple inheritance causes ambiguities such as the one you describe : `A` has an abstract method `get()` and `B` has the same method but implemented. Since `A` and `B` have no relation then which method is inherited in `C` probably depends on the fact that get() in `A` is still not implemented. (The fact that `B` implements it is useless since B does not have any relation to `A`)